# I am attempting to add two models from separate local apps into one template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to access Content from content.models and Post from Post.models in the blog.html template. The idea for Content is to be able to edit text on the site through the django admin.

The directory stucture is as follows:

```
 - src [Folder] 
   - content [Folder]
     - migrations [Folder]
     - __init__.py
     - admin.py
     - apps.py
     - models.py
     - tests.py
     - views.py
  - main [Folder]
     - settings [Folder]
         - __init__.py
         - base.py
     - migrations [Folder]
     - __init__.py
     - db.sqlite3
     - models.py
     - urls.py
     - views.py
     - wsgi.py
  - posts [Folder]
     - migrations [Folder]
     - templatetags [Folder]
     - __init__.py
     - admin.py
     - apps.py
     - forms.py
     - models.py
     - tests.py
     - urls.py
     - utils.py
     - views.py
    - templates
     - base.html
     - blogbase.html
```

views.py - main looks is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView, TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin


# from posts.models import Post, Content
# from app.models import *
from posts.models import Post
from content.models import Content

class DashboardTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base.html"
    context_object_name = 'name'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DashboardTemplateView,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["title"] = "This is about us"
        return context

class MyView(ContextMixin, TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = {'content_list' : Content.objects.all(), 'post_list':Post.objects.all()}
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

my models.py - main is as follows:

```
from django.db import models

from post.models import Post
from context.models import Contest
```

my urls.py - main is as follows:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from django.views.generic import ListView

from accounts.views import (login_view, register_view, logout_view)
# from views import *

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^comments/', include("comments.urls", namespace='comments')),

    url(r'^register/', register_view, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/', login_view, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts')),


    # The line below does not work
    # url(r'^', DashboardTemplateView.as_view(template_name=('base.html')), name='name'),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I add in the line that doesn't work

```
url(r'^', DashboardTemplateView.as_view(template_name=('base.html')), name='name'),
```

to the url patterns I get the following error

> File
>   "blog/src/main/urls.py",
>   line 39, in 
>       url(r'^', DashboardTemplateView.as_view(template_name=('base.html')),
>   name='name'), NameError: name 'DashboardTemplateView' is not defined

I am using django 1.9 and python 2.7

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have anything to do with "two models from separate apps". Simply, if you want to use a name in a file, you need to import it.

Comment: I am confused, have I not imported it?

Comment: Where do you think you have done that?

Comment: My url routing seems to be on the fritz now however. /blog and /blog/create now go to the root domain? Any ideas @DanielRoseman ?

Comment: Well your DashboardTemplateView pattern is just `^`, which means "all strings that start", ie everything. What did you want to accept for that view?

Comment: Only the root domain. Previously the urls.py in post routed /blog to a list view of all posts and /blog/create to form.

Comment: You mean `/`? Then you need to restrict your pattern to `^$`, ie the empty string.

Comment: That restricts it but doesn't find the /blog or /blog/create anymore. Have I overridden something without realizing it?

Comment: When I try to add a post from django admin I get the following error now as well:  AttributeError at /admin/posts/post/add/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150162/discussion-between-chris-and-daniel-roseman).

Comment: Have you tried adding "from posts import views as posts_view" to your urls.py? Then reference it as "posts_view. DashboardTemplateView" in the actual url itself.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your urls.py has no access to DashboardTemplateView because you have not imported it. To solve this:

1. Import this module into your urls.py, by typing:

   from posts import views as posts_views
2. When you are building your url, reference it as posts_views.DashboardTemplateView instead of just DashboardTemplateView

   url(r'^', posts_view.DashboardTemplateView.as_view(template_name=('base.html')), name='name'),

Hope this helps.